# adding checkbox to ssrs tablix that will be manually clicked

Tags: checkbox, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created a stock taking report in SSRS 2008. I have also added an extra column in the tablix.
The extra column I added is a column I want to have the option to manually click on the checkbox if item is in stock.

I have tried using the wingdings option using the below expression:
**=iif(Fields!Expr1.Value,chr(252),chr(251))**
However the result I get is not the desired result, because I get about 6 winging characters back instead of the check and uncheck boxes I required

How could I go about fixing this ?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use an Indicator, but I've preferred to use images for similar situations. Embed the two needed images in the report and switch between those dynamically. (You can make standard images of your characters in MS Paint or Paint.NET.)

Images have the disadvantage that they don't print with high resolution, but they do render on  most devices (not .csv) and you don't need to worry about installed fonts on the server.

As far as fixing your immediate problem, try changing the "Markup Type" for your placeholder (Placeholder Properties -> General -> Markup type.) It sounds like something is trying to generate HTML when it shouldn't be.